# How close can an electric water heater and an electric furnace be to each other?

Tags: water-heater, furnace

How close can an electric water heater and an electric furnace be to each other?

My water heater is 7 inches from my furnace. I need 4 inches so that I can install a water softener and wash sink. So I need to know if it is OK to move the water heater over by 4 inches, so that I can put them in.

Comment: Have you checked with the furnace maker for clearance specifications?

Answer (score 2):

Each appliance has a specification, available from the manufacturer, on various clearances.  This number is sometimes zero, usually not, but never more than a few inches.

That said 3 inches between the furnace and water heater does not sound risky.  Water heaters stay cool compared to furnaces: the clearance to the water softener may be the bigger deal. Your water softener counts as a 'combustible' surface.